# Find Page for a value in a list

Tags: .net

What is the best and nicest solution to find the page for a value in a list that is for example paged by 10.

So I have `int 0-1000`. I page by `10`. So `23` will be at page `3`.

Who has got a nice solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Int pageNumber = (Int) Math.Ceiling(((Double) (item.Index + 1) / (Double) itemsPerPage));
```

This is assuming that you know what item you are looking for and that the list doesn't start at 0, if it does then add one to the index.

I'm going to expaund on this answer since people seem to be having trouble with it. Also I corrected for starting at 0.

In C# integer division returns as such

anything that is a fraction part is floored or rounded down, so simply doing integer division on the items index and the number of items in a page.

For the below explanation consider that the numerator is `(index + 1)`
`23 / 10 = 2`, which isn't true, since the item is on the third page. Adding 1 to the answer doesn't solve the problem since 20 / 10 = 2 + 1 = 3 which isn't correct since this item is on the 2nd page.

By casting to double's we cause double division to happen

`double / double` returns a `double`. Then taking the Ceiling of that rounds up giving us the page we are on.

Comment: yeah that´s the best solution, great! +1

Comment: i would like to mark this as an answer, but i´m still not allowed to, you were to fast :) 6 minutes remaining...

Comment: @Luke, gotta be fast to get the oldest answer  in.

Comment: This is wrong, the first 11 items will all be on the first page.  Items 0-9 should be on the first page, items 10-19 on the second.

Comment: The 11th item is index 10 if you are zero based.  So for the 11th item, you have index 10, which is ceil(10/10) = 1.  I may be wrong, but I don't think so.

Comment: in this case it would be still better i think to do index + 1 / 10 -> ceil.

Comment: What's the reason for using floating-point arithmetic to solve a trivial integer problem?

Comment: because in C# 5 / 10 = 0 in integer division.

Comment: I don't understand why this solution is better than Alan's "ndx / 10 + 1". I'd like to know if I'm misunderstanding basic math in C#, because if the actual results are the same (which I'm pretty sure they are), I think using the inherent floor in integer division is a more elegant, readable solution.

Answer (score 2):

No need to round, and then use ceiling.  Integer division will do a floor, then just add 1.

```
int page = ndx / 10 + 1;
```

or for a generic number of pages:

```
int page = ndx / perPage + 1
```

If your first item is 1, you just need to add one to the index

```
int page = (ndx + 1) / perPage + 1
```

Comment: @AlanJackson what if it's 10, 10/10 + 1 =  2, but it's on the first page!

Comment: he started at 0, so 10 should be the first element of the 2nd page.  0-9, 10-19, etc....

Comment: what is with 5/10 and my first item is 1?

Comment: @Luke because integer division only returns the integer portion of the item. so 5/10 = 0.5, 0.5 to int is 0.

Comment: If your first item is one, then you just have to add one to your index.  Also, you add one to the result, so 5/10+1 = 0+1 = 1

Answer (score 0):

divide your integer by 10 and round up!

Comment: ah but integer division truncates

Comment: I concede the superiority of your solution, but could also just add 1.

Comment: so just add 1 to the truncation.  Integer division and addition is MUCH faster than double division then a ceiling (though it probably doesn't matter).  Also, I think the code is much cleaner without so many casts and functions.

Comment: alas, 2 minutes too late, could have spared my pride.